# Set Default FlowDirection Wpf toolkit extended MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

Am unable to set the default flowdirection property for the WPF Toolkit Extended 1.6 MessageBox **dynamically**, is there any way to do that in code & at runtime knowing that I've a static field `myFlowDirection`

i've tried **its working fine** & it changes the flow but i need it **dynamically**

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:MessageBox}">
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection"  Value="RightToLeft"/>
        </Style>
```

this MessageBox can't be derived & has no constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but have you tried binding the Setter Property?

This link is a question from SO that sounds similar to yours:

[WPF binding to another property's binding in a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793723/wpf-binding-to-another-propertys-binding-in-a-style)

Here's another example:

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/130096.aspx/1

Comment: Yes i've already tried an `IValueConverter` that works fine, but slowly, so the window Shows then the FlowDirection property changes *about 300ms* , even if I've an i7Core processor and an excellent graphic card

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able to set your message box **FlowDirection** by *MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading*

For Example:

`MessageBox.Show("Your RTL Text", "Message Box Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.None, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);`